# C# What is the best way to compare a double value to a range of values and return two text values

Tags: c#, dictionary, range

I have a project that is in C# but I don't know the best way to use a value (Which can range from 1500 to -1500) to compare with a range of 9 values and return two string values associated with one of the 9 possible range values.

So far, I have done some research and I believe that a dictionary would be fastest to do this, so I created one as an example to show you the data:

```
class MyTICKObject
{
public double MyDouble  { get; set; }
public string MyString1 { get; set; }
public string MyString2 { get; set; }
}

private Dictionary<double, MyTICKObject>    dictTICK = new  Dictionary<double, MyTICKObject>();

int i = dictTICK.Keys.Count();      
    if( i == 0)
    {
        dictTICK.Add(1000,  new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=1000,  MyString1="Extreme Bullish", MyString2="DarkSeaGreen"});
        dictTICK.Add(600,   new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=600,   MyString1="Strong Bullish",  MyString2="Lime"});
        dictTICK.Add(400,   new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=400,   MyString1="Bullish",         MyString2="Green"});
        dictTICK.Add(100,   new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=100,   MyString1="Positive",        MyString2="DarkGreen"});
        dictTICK.Add(0,     new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=0,     MyString1="Neutral",         MyString2="DarkGray"});
        dictTICK.Add(-100,  new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=-100,  MyString1="Negative",        MyString2="DarkRed"});
        dictTICK.Add(-400,  new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=-400,  MyString1="Extreme Bearish", MyString2="FireBrick"});
        dictTICK.Add(-600,  new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=-600,  MyString1="Strong Bearish",  MyString2="Red"});
        dictTICK.Add(-1000, new MyTICKObject { MyDouble=-1000, MyString1="Extreme Bearish", MyString2="IndianRed"});
    }
```

What I want to do is compare the incoming TICK values (201,-12,456, etc.) with MyDouble, find it's position between two MyDouble values then return MyString2 to a variable called strStmnt, and return MyString2 to a variable called strColor.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Okay, so do that. You have described virtually all of the desired operation in pseudo-code, so now just write it.

Comment: So you receive a `201` TICK value; according to your dictionary, wich values should you return?

Comment: Josh Part, 201 would be above 100 and below 400 so I would return the values associated with 100 which are "Positive", and "DarkGreen". Thank you for clarifying my requirements further.

Comment: Mark Benningfield, You assume I am as smart as you.  I am not, sorry, not when it comes to c# syntax.

Comment: How about using a list with a binary search? Would only take about 3 iterations at most to find the number you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a dictionary, just make a list (or array if you're happy to write it all at once) since you already ordered it and the MyTICK object contains the stop.  Then you can just iterate through the list from top to bottom with a while loop until you reach the right range stop values.  Also be aware that you've defined a set of stops and assigned names to each stop but really you want one less name than stops to be able to assign the in-between values of the input double.

I've given an example below which wouldn't work very well because of the stop-values == names problem I mentioned but it should give you the right idea.

```
private MyTICKObject[] list = new MyTICKObject[]
            {
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = 1000, MyString1 = "Extreme Bullish", MyString2 = "DarkSeaGreen" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = 600, MyString1 = "Strong Bullish", MyString2 = "Lime" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = 400, MyString1 = "Bullish", MyString2 = "Green" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = 100, MyString1 = "Positive", MyString2 = "DarkGreen" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = 0, MyString1 = "Neutral", MyString2 = "DarkGray" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = -100, MyString1 = "Negative", MyString2 = "DarkRed" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = -400, MyString1 = "Extreme Bearish", MyString2 = "FireBrick" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = -600, MyString1 = "Strong Bearish", MyString2 = "Red" },
                new MyTICKObject { MyDouble = -1000, MyString1 = "Extreme Bearish", MyString2 = "IndianRed" },
            };

public MyTICKObject findAt(double value)
    {
        foreach (MyTICKObject tick in list)
        {
            if (value < tick.MyDouble)
            {
                return tick;
            }
        }
    throw new ArgumentException("Value out of range");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ross Batten, I used your code but it only returned "MyTICKObject", I would like for it to return the string values individually instead. I'll keep trying variations, maybe it is just a little thing to fix.

Comment: The MyTicketObject contains the strings you're interested in.  You obviously tried to print to console or something similiar with the object which made it call the ToString method (if nothing is specified this command simply returns the object type as a string).

Use ".MyString1" and ".MyString2" from the object the findAt method returned to get the two strings from it.

Comment: Hi Ross Batten, Thank you for your response.  I added .MyString1 to return tick but get an error that says Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to MyTICKObject Yet I defined MyString1 as a string when creating the object.  I even tried adding .ToString() after that but still get the error. I will keep trying and researching but have not found a great help resource so sorry to bother you further.